# Scifi/fantasy book about two characters that can control time

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book a few years ago:  2 stories interlinked. 1 is set in the future, the second is set on a distant old world.  The main old world character is a villager who has "special powers" he does not what they are, but as he gets older he realises through will, he can control time.  There is some link between the second character's ability to control time, and the first character's world being taken away.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already, but could you please take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? Perhaps the most important - how long ago is "a few years ago"? Asw ell as anything that the guide would remind you of, even if seems minor - everything may help in getting you an answer. Cheers :)